# My Ubuntu 22.04 Lts has been flickering

Tags: command-line, 22.04, flicker, autorun

My Ubuntu 22.04 Lts started to flicker after I tried to run the command ./autorun.sh in the command terminal. Can you please help me with this problem

Comment: What is `autorun.sh`: which package did it come from?

Comment: It comes from the VBox_Gas_7.0.14 package. It helps for enlarging the display according to your desktop size

Comment: Can you get all the functionality you need from `sudo apt install virtualbox virtualbox-guest-additions-iso virtualbox-guest-{utils,x11}` instead?

Comment: Hey should I just install the package maintainer's version

Comment: @moo Thankyou brother it worked